# Why are there different fonts for ToolStrip controls (Segoe UI 16) and all other controls (Microsoft Sans Serif 13)?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, windows-10, .net-4.7.2

I'm using Winforms to build a GUI for my application, and I saw that the default font of a ToolStrip control is different than of all other controls on the form.

- For a ToolStrip control the default font is: Segoe UI, Size 9, Height 16
- For all other controls on the form the default font is: Microsoft Sans Serif, Size 8.25, Height 13

See as well the following two screen shots:

[image]

or with DPI scaling set to 160% and `DPIAwareness`

[image]

They were created using the following code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    toolStripLabel1.Text = "Font: " + toolStripLabel1.Font.FontFamily.Name + ", Size: " + toolStripLabel1.Font.Size + ", Height: " + toolStripLabel1.Font.Height;
    label1.Text = "Font: " + label1.Font.FontFamily.Name + ", Size: " + label1.Font.Size + ", Height: " + label1.Font.Height;
    textBox1.Text = "Font: " + textBox1.Font.FontFamily.Name + ", Size: " + textBox1.Font.Size + ", Height: " + textBox1.Font.Height;
}
```

So what should I do about that?

Should I use Segoe UI for everthing?

Comment: Many controls inherit the Font from their Parent container and will also re-apply the Parent's Font when it's changed. `ToolStripLabel` inherits it from the parent ToolStrip (Segoe UI is its default Font), Label and TextBox inherits it from the Form (MS Sans Serif is the default). Unless you specify the Font explicitly, setting it to a specific Font (which can also be the same as the Parent's). In this case, setting the Parent's Font won't change the child Controls' Font. You set the Font to what's more appropriate for the Control's destination/function and the application overall *look*.

Comment: @Jimi Tanks for your comment. I didn't specify any font (not even int the Designer.cs file).  But they have different default fonts.

Comment: As already described, if you don't explicitly set a child Control's Font, the Font is inherited from the Parent. Your Form has its default `Microsoft Sans Serif` Font and the ToolStrip its default `Segoe UI` Font. The former is quite old, it's often substituted with a more *modern* Font (and for other reasons). The Font is decided when the application is designed; it can be quite a complex decision, based on the application destination, it's *market position* and many other factors.